# UINavigationController from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I currently have this workflow in a tab based app:

Tab1 loads...

```
ViewOne : UIViewController
  >> 
    PickerView : UIViewController
    >> 
       DetailView : UIViewController
```

">>" means loads based on user action.  I'd like navigation bars on PickerView and DetailView.  PickerView just needs a cancel button in the top left of its nav bar.  DetailView needs the normal navbar back button.  I already have PickerView's nav bar wired up through IB and working.  I'm not sure what to do with PickerView's nav bar.

PickerView is also loaded from Tab2, who's main view starts as a UINavigationController.  PickerView's nav bar works fine in that case.

ViewOne should not have a navigation bar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just do the usual: in ViewOne, create your nav controller as:

```
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
[self.view addSubview:nc.view];
[nc release];
```

Back buttons are created automatically (unless you need one to get back from your picker to viewOne, in which case create one.

Sounds like you want to present DetailView as a modal:

[self presentModalViewController:detailView animated:YES];

although you could just use it within a navigation controller normally.

Sounds like you are perhaps worrying too much about the mechanics of navigation when the navigation controller can do it all for you?

Comment: It actually needs to be addSubview:nc.view.  When I do this, the added view is pushed down enough that I can see the first view behind it.  Seem like the same amount of space that the status bar takes up. Do you have any ideas what causes this?

Comment: Code fixed, thanks.  View transforms under nav and tab bars are something we have to live with; make sure that your view are created with correct autoresizeMasks, which is easy to do if you set them up in IB, using the "springs & struts" settings.

Comment: By "springs & struts", if you mean the all of the autoresizing arrows in IB are visible, I have that.  Yet, I still get PickerView and any view it pushes being pushed down by the size of the status bar.

Comment: I had to add this bit of code to make it work: 
  self.nc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 380, 460);